# Present perfect or simple past "have moved or moved?"

Tags: grammar

I have just read the sentence like this: ***" I haven't seen her since 2003. She moved to Australia with her family then"***. My question is: Why don't we use "she has moved to Australia then"? I have learnt that the present perfect is used for indefinite time in the past and in this sentence we don't know the definite time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Present perfect is a **present** tense and is not used with modifiers like *then* which exclude the present. See [*What is the perfect, and how should I use it?*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32)

Answer (score 8):

The present perfect is used to speak about the current state. You can't use the present perfect with a time expression that excludes the present.

> She has moved to Australia (and so she is there now).

The adverb "then" is giving the time when an event happened. If you are speaking about a past time, you must use a past tense:

> She moved to Australia [then = in 2003].

Comment: Now I know what the difference is. Thank you so much for your answer.